# Can I dynamically create a table layout in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, tablelayout

I'm making an app where there's one main activity that is a Fragment. I basically have a few tabs and each tab/page layout I want a different layout. For one of them, I want to know if I can dynamically create a table of, say 20-ish rows with X amount of columns. Instead of having to manually create each row inside the layout .axml file.

The reason for wanting to dynamically create it is that I'm obtaining some data from online that I want to automatically put inside a table.

Answer (score 1):

You will only need to create 1 layout for the item and it will be your item 'template' to inflate it into your ListView dynamically. Take a look at this [RecyclerView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/) example (which is the improved ListView)